# Need help multiprocessing this coding

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am writing numbers in this coding to file, but do to amount of numbers in the numbers needed it takes hours to write using only one process.

```
from multiproccessing import Pool

print('What number would you like to start at?')
datastart = raw_input() #user input for datastart

x= int(datastart) #sets x to datastart

print('What number would you like to end at?')
dataend= raw_input() #user input to question at hand and sets var.

print('would you like to write file in normal or reverse? \n (n/r)')
detailer=raw_input() #sets forward or reverse writing mode

print('what password length would you like?')
passwordlen=int(raw_input())# sets length of file to be writen

print('Please wait while file is created!')
f=open(str(datastart)+'-'+str(dataend)+'-'+str(passwordlen)+'.txt','a')

def NumberCrunch(nc):

    while detailer == 'n':
        x=datastart
        while x <= int(dataend):
            num= str(x)
            while len(num) < passwordlen:
                num='0'+num
            if len(num) == passwordlen:
                f.write(num+'\n')
            x+=1


    while detailer == 'r':
        x=int(dataend)
        while x >= int(datastart):
            num= str(x)
            while len(num) < passwordlen:
                num='0'+num
            if len(num +'\n'):
                f.write(num +'\n')


            x-=1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(process = 16) as p:
        p.map(NumberCrunch,chunksize =10)
        p.close()
        p.join()


f.close()
print('File has been created! Enjoy!')
```

I am using a server running python 2.7 64bit, duel xeon 2.20 dual quad core with 16 cores total, 32gb ram, and 3 tesla cards. modify the Pool(process =(your number of cpu cores)) to insure it runs on your computer.

I am trying to use all cores to process the data range from datastart to dataend, in forward write mode or dataend to datastart in reverse write mode.
I have tried multiprocessing, Queue. still only using one process or raised system exit.

Is there a better way to write the program for multiprocessing, or am i missing something.

would it be better to use this instead:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

print('What number would you like to start at?')
datastart = raw_input() #user input for datastart

x= int(datastart) #sets x to datastart

print('What number would you like to end at?')
dataend= raw_input() #user input to question at hand and sets var.

print('would you like to write file in normal or reverse? \n (n/r)')
detailer=raw_input() #sets forward or reverse writing mode

print('what password length would you like?')
passwordlen=int(raw_input())# sets length of file to be writen

print('Please wait while file is created!')
f=open(str(datastart)+'-'+str(dataend)+'-'+str(passwordlen)+'.txt','a')

def NumberCrunch(nc):
    while detailer == 'f':
        for i in range(datastart,dataend,1):
            num = str(i)
            while len(num) < passwordlen:
                num = '0' + num
            if len(num)== passwordlen:
                f.write(num+'n')
    while detailer == 'r':
        for i in range(dataend,datastart,-1):
            num= str(i)
            while len(num) < passwordlen:
                num = '0'+num
            if len(num)== passwordlen:
                f.write(num+'\n')
if __name__=='__main____':
    with Pool(process = 16) as p:
        p.map(Numbercrunch,i,chuncksize=10)
        p.close()
        p.join()
f.close()
p.close()
print('File has been created')
```

Any ideas or help would help greatly. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: `while detailer == 'n':` - when do you expect `detailer` to *stop* being `'n'`?

Comment: typo supposed to be 'f'. I will edit that codiing.

Comment: Your code is a sloppy mess with many errors.  You are in way over your head.  Buy a beginning python book. Read it.  Work your way up.

Comment: You have a function `def NumberCrunch(nc):` that takes a single parameter... and then you don't use that parameter. `p.map(NumberCrunch,chunksize =10)` raises an exception because you are missing the iterator. You have a more fundamental problem in that you haven't carved your algorithm up into parallel chunks. If you got it working, all the the child process would do all of the work.

Answer (score 0):

When I have used multiprocessing I used Process instead of Pool.  Like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def main_process(myargs):
    #do stuff here

#main_data defined elsewhere with items inside.
for k,myargs in main_data.items(): 
    p = Process(target=main_process, args=(myargs,))
    p.start()
```

Comment: thank you i will give this a try. I haven't tried the process yet.

Comment: changing to process Worked Beautifully, used 98% of cpu processing power and wrote the entire file in minutes. Thank you greatly for the response.

Comment: @Mikey if this solved your questions, please click the check mark to indicate it is the answer.  Thanks